# Java substring method: How to remove all non-alphanumerical characters?

Tags: java, substring

I would like to remove all non-alphanumerical characters from this string, and other types of strings like this one

```
Unable_to_locate_element_{"method""link_text","selector""ikljbhfvdesiofsdjkl"}
```

So I can use this string in order to generate a name for a screenshot in this code:

```
    private String generateRandomFilename(Throwable arg0) {
      Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

      String filename = arg0.getMessage();
      int i = filename.indexOf('\n');
      filename = filename.substring(0, i).replaceAll("\\s", "_").replaceAll(":", "") + ".jpg";
      filename = "" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 
          "-" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 
          "-" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) +
          "-" + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) +
          "-" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) +
          "-" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND) +
          "-" + filename;

      return filename;
  }
```

The way it is now, my file creation breakes because of not all bad characters being removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\P{Alnum}", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
  str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\W", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way if you don't want to use `regex`:

```
    String str = "something : but / nothing@*/132456+";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();        
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(str.charAt(i))){
            sb.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

It shows`somethingbutnothing132456`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
String str = str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
System.out.println(str);
```